# How to get a ball/sphere to stop

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I got a field in unity3d that has some depressions in it (like small holes). The field's slope always leads towards the nearest depression.
A sphere is dropped at random somewhere in the field, rolls around a bit until it stops in one of the depressions.

The problem is, this is taking too long. It could roll around for 5-10 seconds until it stops. I'd like to stop faster.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Edit: The main issue is when the ball is next to the depression, but it has speed that is 90 degrees from the hole, then it starts going in circles and takes a while to stop.

Comment: You could add your own damping script that measures change in position relative to the nearest depression.  If that change remains continuously less than some threshold, terminate the sphere's velocity.

Comment: I want it to stop in the middle of the depression... but I could apply constant force towards the nearest depression's center, that might work. I'll try, thanks.

Comment: If you are using physics (it seems to be the case), you could also increase dynamic friction of the physic material.

Comment: Wouldn't increasing the gravity work as well?

Comment: Increasing dynamic friction didn't work (maybe because it's a ball?). I don't want to increase the gravity because it will affect other game mechanics. I did increase the mass but it didn't have too much of an effect either.

Comment: @tbkn Take what I said w/ a grain of salt.  Once you terminate the velocity you can have the same script gently ease your sphere in to the depression.  For me, that's an easier path than trying to kludge the physics engine in to doing something very specific.

Comment: @Jerdak the ball usually doesn't slow down enough for your recommendation to work as is... it just keeps going in circles between the depressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after getting some advice in the comments, and experimenting, this is the way I solved it:

1. Apply a small measure of strength towards the depression
2. If the current velocity is more than 30 degrees away from the center of the depression, slow the ball (apply strength in the opposite direction of the velocity)
3. IF the ball gets very near the center of the depression, stop it and place it in the center

Thanks for all the tips. If anyone comes up with a better way, I'm still open to suggestions.